# JsonTypeInfo is broken when subclasses have members and the root class is a member of a wrapper class

Tags: json, inheritance, polymorphism, jackson, wrapper

TL;DR - A wrapper class that has a member that is a List of an abstract class that is annotated with `@JsonTypeInfo` is broken.

---

I have a wrapper class and a class hierarchy with a root abstract class, one child abstract class, and one concrete grandchild.

```
public static class RootClassWrapper {
    public static final String JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_LIST =
        "root_class_list";

    @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_LIST)
    private final List<RootClass> rootClassList;

    @JsonCreator
    public RootClassWrapper(
        @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_LIST)
            final List<RootClass> rootClassList) {

        this.rootClassList = rootClassList;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = RootClass.JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_TYPE)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = GrandchildClass.class,
        name = GrandchildClass.CHILD_CLASS_TYPE) })
public static abstract class RootClass {
    public static final String JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_TYPE = "root_class_type";
    public static final String JSON_KEY_ID = "id";

    @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID)
    private final String id;

    @JsonCreator
    public RootClass(
        @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID) final String id) {

        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static abstract class ChildClass extends RootClass {
    @JsonCreator
    public ChildClass(
        @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID) final String id) {

        super(id);
    }
}

public static class GrandchildClass extends ChildClass {
    public static final String CHILD_CLASS_TYPE = "grandchild";

    @JsonCreator
    public GrandchildClass(
        @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID) final String id) {

        super(id);
    }
}
```

Attempting to then utilize this hierarchy:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GrandchildClass grandchildClass = new GrandchildClass("grandchildId");
List<RootClass> rootClassList = new ArrayList<RootClass>(1);
rootClassList.add(grandchildClass);
RootClassWrapper wrapper = new RootClassWrapper(rootClassList);
mapper.writeValue(out, wrapper);
System.out.println(out.toString());

RootClassWrapper rootClassWrapper =
    mapper.readValue(out.toString(), RootClassWrapper.class);
mapper.writeValue(System.out, rootClassWrapper);
```

The object can be serialized, which can be observed by `System.out.println(out.toString());`:

```
{"root_class_list":[{"root_class_type":"grandchild","id":"grandchildId"}]}
```

But the deserialization of that same output causes the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class test.Test$RootClass)
    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@13de68e2; line: 1, column: 1]
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:584)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:551)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:267)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:405)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:354)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:267)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:305)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:151)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:309)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.construct(PropertyBasedCreator.java:96)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:414)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:298)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:322)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2990)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2884)
       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
       at test.Test.main(Test.java:130)
```

Comment: This still crashes even if the list is empty and there are no `RootClass` objects to deserialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is still a bug, but this works**

Creating a private, default constructor for the `RootClass`, marking it with `@JsonCreator`,  and removing the annotations from the existing constructor seems to work. The `@JsonCreator` annotation on the intermediate, abstract classes is irrelevant.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = RootClass.JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_TYPE)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = GrandchildClass.class,
        name = GrandchildClass.CHILD_CLASS_TYPE) })
public static abstract class RootClass {
    public static final String JSON_KEY_ROOT_CLASS_TYPE = "root_class_type";
    public static final String JSON_KEY_ID = "id";

    @JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID)
    private final String id;

    @JsonCreator
    private RootClass() {
        id = null;
    }

    public RootClass(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static abstract class ChildClass extends RootClass {

    /**
     * The annotations here don't matter.
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public ChildClass(@JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID) final String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}

public static class GrandchildClass extends ChildClass {
    public static final String CHILD_CLASS_TYPE = "grandchild";

    @JsonCreator
    public GrandchildClass(@JsonProperty(JSON_KEY_ID) final String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```